# Plotting a double integral with variable limits

Tags: numerical-integration

I need to plot the following double integral

$\sigma(t)=\sum_{p=2}^N\int_0^td\tau_1\int_0^td\tau_2e^{-|\tau_1-\tau_2|/\tau_A}\tau_1^{\alpha-1}\tau_2^{\alpha-1}E_{\alpha,\alpha}[-(\tau_1/\tau_p)^{\alpha}]E_{\alpha,\alpha}[-(\tau_2/\tau_p)^{\alpha}]$

where the E is the Mittag-Leffler function.

I tried to do it the following way:

```
s[t_?NumericQ] := Sum[NIntegrate[
     Exp[-Abs[t2 - t1]/tA] * t1^(a-1) * t2^(a-1) * 
     MittagLefflerE[a, a, -(t1/tp[[p]])^a] * MittagLefflerE[a, a, -(t2/tp[[p]])^a], 
     {t1, 0, t}, {t2, 0, t}
], {p, 2, n}];

LogLogPlot[s[t], {t,0.001,1000}]
```

where

```
a = 0.7;
tA = 0.01;
tp = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5};
n = Length[tp];
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't produce any result for me, Mathematica just keeps calculating. Does anybody know how to get a plot of this function?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are `a`, `tA`, `tp` and `n` defined?

Comment: a=0.7, tA=0.01, tp is  list of eigenvalues of a matrix and n is the length of this list. For simplicity we can just use tp={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5} or something like that

Comment: Should `tp` be `tp[[p]]`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Let me tell you something you already know. *Mathematica* doesn't work on magic.

Running the code for just one value of `t`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Sum[NIntegrate[
   Exp[-Abs[t2 - t1]/tA]*t1^(a - 1)*t2^(a - 1)*
    MittagLefflerE[a, a, -(t1/tp[[p]])^a]*
    MittagLefflerE[a, a, -(t2/tp[[p]])^a], {t1, 0, 1}, {t2, 0, 
    1}], {p, 2, n}]]
```

> `{124.122, 0.028238}`

That's over two minutes, for a range of $\left[0,1\right]$, you can imagine how long this takes for $\left[0,1000\right]$.

As @Michael-E2 suggested transposing the `Integral[]` and the `Sum[]` could tweak performance, as well as standard methods such as reducing `AccuracyGoal`, but this will not make the crunching time manageable.

How would I plot this? Book time at a supercomputer.

Comment: You can save some time by lowering `AccuracyGoal` (at least for plotting), but I couldn't set it less than `AccuracyGoal -> 6` and get a seemingly accurate result. It cut the time only in 1/2 or 1/3.  Still quite slow. -- (Oh, and I transposed the integral and the sum.)